# Prevent magit-status from closing hunk preview window when magit-status buffer close

Tags: magit

I configured magit-status to open selected buffer change hunk in other window rather then in the same window with:

```lisp
    (setq magit-display-file-buffer-function
      (lambda (buffer)
        (setq current-prefix-arg t)
        (magit-display-file-buffer-traditional buffer)))
```

Now when I close status buffer the other window is closed as well and I assume window state is bring back to the one before magit-status was opened.

How can I keep this window and buffer open after closing magit-status window. The solution would be to prevent magit from restoring windows status before magit-status was opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```elisp
(setq magit-bury-buffer-function 'magit-mode-quit-window)
```

Also see the [Modes and Buffers](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Modes-and-Buffers.html) node.